# The foreign key property '' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name ''

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

The entire error:

> The foreign key property 'Appointment.CustomerId1' was created in a shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'CustomerId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.

Tables:

[Appointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlJtj.png)

[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jim7x.png)

In the Appointment table, I had 2 FKs: one pointing to the Customer Table (Id Column) and the other to Employee Table (Id Column). See the picture at the BEFORE section.
But now, because I will have all users (customer + employee) in the same table User, it has to change. That means that in the Appointment table I need to have 2 FKs but both need to point to the same table User, and the Id column.
I want the CustomerId and EmployeeId to point to the Id from the User.

It creates 3 extra columns: UserId, CustomerId1, and EmployeeId1--which I don't want.
I only used Conventions for the relationships, no Data Annotations or Fluent API.

There are 3 things that can cause the error:

- 1. not mapped
- 2. already used for another relationship
- 3. incompatible with the associated primary key type

By my understanding

- 3. is not my case, because the data type is the same (string).
- 2. is not my case because I have no other relationship.
- 1. There might be a problem but I'm not sure. I might need to add some Fluent Api for this mapping.
     This is what I've tried but it's not working:
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFrC6.png

Bi-directional method:

User class:

```
public ICollection<Appointment> AppointmentCustomers { get; set; }
public ICollection<Appointment> AppointmentEmployees { get; set; }
```

Appointment class:

```
public string CustomerId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
public User Customer { get; set; }

public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
public User Employee { get; set; }
```

OnModelCreating method:

```
builder.Entity<Appointment>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Customer)
    .WithMany(app => app.AppointmentCustomers)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.CustomerId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

builder.Entity<Appointment>()
    .HasOne(u => u.Employee)
    .WithMany(app => app.AppointmentEmployees)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.EmployeeId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please don't repeat code in prose. Please don't include text in images or add redundant images.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before, EF could work out the keys by convention. The convention being based on the Type name (Employee vs. Customer) rather than the variable name. If you had named the FKs EmployeeKey/EmpID and CustomerKey/CustID you would have had a similar problem. EF's convention wouldn't have associated those as the FKs so it would have created shadow properties.

Now that you are pointing these both at the same Type (User) EF cannot use convention, so you have to be explicit. The easiest way to fix that is to use the `[ForeignKey]` attribute. This can either be put on the FK property to point at the navigation property, or on the navigation property to point at the FK.

I.e.

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Customer))]
public string CustomerId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(Employee))]
public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

public virtual User Customer { get; set; }
public virtual User Employee { get; set; }
```

or

```
public string CustomerId { get; set; }
public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))]
public virtual User Customer { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(EmployeeId))]
public virtual User Employee { get; set; }
```

Edit:

The error you are now getting is because User has a collection of Appointments but you'd have to tell EF which collection this FK links to. Here you have an appointment which references two users, a customer and an employee. From the User perspective there are 2 distinct relationships.  Appointments-I-am-a-Customer and Appointments-I-am-an-Employee.

If you are interested in only one relationship you need to configure EF to map User.Appointments based on the Appointment Customer or Employee relationship. If you are interested in both then you have two options.

a) Add 2 Appointments collections to User, i.e. AppointmentsAsCustomer and AppointmentsAsEmployee and set up the mappings in ModelBuilder or an EntityTypeConfiguration.
b) Remove the Appointments collection on User and configure EF with a `.HasOne(x => x.Customer).WithMany()` and `.HasOne(x => x.Employee).WithMany()` then when you want to query appointments by a user, do it from Appointments rather than expecting to navigate via User:

instead of:

```
var appointmentsForUser = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Appointments) // can't work for both asEmployee and asCustomer
    .ToList();
```

use:

```
var appointmentsForUser = context.Appointments
    .Where(a => a.Customer.UserId == userId 
       || a.Employee.UserId == userId) // if you want appts where user is customer or employee
    .ToList();
```

Bi-directional references (where Apointments has a reference to user(s) and User has a reference to Appointments) should be used sparingly only as absolutely required rather than by default. They can lead to weird behavior when updating plus lazy loading implications, and "gotchas" like this with ambiguous relationships.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the fast and explicit response. I do understand my mistake now, the name is important.

However, I did what you told me, and tried both your examples (even tho they are the same), and now when I try to add the migration, I have this new error:
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Appointment.Customer' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I will try to solve it but do you have any idea what is it?

Comment: I've expanded the answer with an explanation for the error that you're now getting as I missed that you had a collection reference to Appointments declared on the User table which will cause problems.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for the late update.
a) I added 2 new collections in the User class:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7t5Y.png
I set them up with FluentAPI in OnModelCreating with ModelBuilder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOgfr.png
I did modify the Appointment class as well:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2nTN.png

b) I removed the 2 new Appointment collections from User.
I did configure them with FluentAPI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRAxP.png
And that's all.

What am I doing wrong? Both methods have the same issue (shadow properties). Is there something that EF overwrites...?
Thank you.

Comment: You don't look to have done what I pointed out in the answer. When you have 2 or more references from one entity to the same entity (Customers and Employees are *both* type User) then you have to tell EF what Foreign Key to use for each of them. EF convention will automatically work out FKs but it does so by the **type** name, not the **property** name. So if the type is "User" it is expecting "UserId", you have to tell it to use "CustomerId". That can be done with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute or using `.HasForeignKey()` in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Hello sir.
I did that if you look at my second picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOgfr.png). There is the .HasForeignKey() and now I did use the Data Annotation as well: [ForeignKey(nameof(Customer))] on the CustomerId property and it still doesn't work.
I did read and follow your comments very carefully and read more data about it and I'm trying my best, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with such a simple task.

Comment: It's confusing what you've done because the last FluentAPI link doesn't have the FK registrations. Without seeing the actual code it will be difficult to see the complete state of of the configuration and pinpoint problems. That cannot be done with selective screenshots.  Consider stripping just those classes, properties, and configurations out into a separate project that reproduces the problem and upload to Github or paste the code into the question. When addressing problems it helps to break things down to a minimum reproducible example to work through.

Comment: I understand, ok. I did edit my question, you can see that under the "Bi-directional method". I hope now my code is clear and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

The property was already used for another relationship from the old Customer and Employee classes.

([Steve Py's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74381351) helps a lot with the foreign key configurations, but from what I've read it's better to configure them through Fluent API vs Data Annotations.)